# How to fetch empty optional accounts in Anchor

Tags: anchor, web3.js, anchor-lang

How can I fetch empty optional accounts in Anchor? For instance I have a simple account in rust with the following optional account:

```
#[account]
pub struct MyApp {
    pub my_optional_account: Option<Pubkey>,
}
```

How could I fetch in JS the accounts whose `my_optional_account`are empty?

```
// Javascript:
myProgram.account.myAccount.all([
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 8,
        bytes: "", // What should I add here to search for empty Pubkeys?
      },
    },
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Anchor generated client is using `getProgramAccounts` underneath to fetch corresponding program accounts. The default encoding for `bytes` is `base58`

So your code would look something like this if you're using base58 utility shipped with Anchor.

```
import { utils } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";

const OPTION_NONE = 0;
// Javascript:
myProgram.account.myAccount.all([
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 8,
        bytes: utils.bytes.bs58.encode([OPTION_NONE])
      },
    },
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like using just `"1"` does the job:

```
// Javascript:
myProgram.account.myAccount.all([
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 8,
        bytes: "1",
      },
    },
])
```